# PL-SQL - First record in a One-to-Many relation left join

Tags: oracle, join, plsql, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables with LEFT JOIN in Oracle. I need to include only the first record from the "right" joined table.

See the example below:

**Table A**

```
code | emp_no

101  | 11111
102  | 22222
103  | 33333
104  | 44444
105  | 55555
```

**Table B**

```
code | city       | county

101  | City1      | Country1
101  | City2      | Country1
101  | City3      | Country1
102  | City4      | Country2
103  | City5      | Country3
```

**Expected Output:**

```
code | emp_no | city      | county

101  | 11111  | City1     | Country1
102  | 22222  | City4     | Country2
103  | 33333  | City5     | Country3
104  | 44444  | NULL      | NULL
105  | 55555  | NULL      | NULL
```

I need to pick the first matched record from table B and ignore all other rows.

The query above suppose to works:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A a
   LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.CODE = a.CODE
      AND b.CODE = 
      (
         SELECT CODE
         FROM TABLE_B
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1
      )
```

But I'm getting the error:
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you deciding which is 'first'?

Comment: Note: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve however by retrieving only `ROWNUM = 1`.   I have written answer anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `min()` aggrenate function with [the `keep (dense_rank first ...)` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) to get the 'first' matching data from the outer-joined table:

```
select a.code, a.emp_no,
  min(b.city) keep (dense_rank first order by city, county) as city,
  min(b.county) keep (dense_rank first order by city, county) as county
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.code = a.code
group by a.code, a.emp_no
order by a.code, a.emp_no;

      CODE     EMP_NO CITY  COUNTY  
---------- ---------- ----- --------
       101      11111 City1 Country1
       102      22222 City4 Country2
       103      33333 City5 Country3
       104      44444               
       105      55555
```

You have to define what 'first' means though - I've gone with order by `city, county` inside the keep clause, but you may have another column you haven't shown that should dictate the order.

(You *can* order by null to make it somewhat arbitrary, but that's not generally a good idea, not least as running the same query later could give different results for the same data.)

Comment: Thanks Alex, worked!

Just to clarify, I’m using BIRT (PL-SQL integrated) and my real situation it is more complicated than this.

1. My “first” row is based on most recently changed (LST_UPD_TSTMP)
2. This issue will JOIN with an existent report that currently contains user’s information, like “ID, Name…”
3. The TABLE_B contains basically: STUD_ID (PK, FK); DEL_STUD_ID (user that received permission over the user) (PK, FK); LST_UPD_TSTMP (NOT NULL)
4. After this I'll need to JOIN again to bring information about DEL_STUD_ID

I'll try to use this query in my report and update here ok?

Comment: @IgorIvanov - then sounds like you need to use `order by lst_upd_tstmp desc` in both `keep` clauses. (Or, if you think it reads better use `last` instead of `first` so you don't need the `desc`: i.e. `max(b.city) keep (dense_rank last order by last_upd_tstmp)` etc.)

Answer (score 6):

On Oracle 12c you can use `OUTER APPLY` and `FETCH FIRST` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA  a
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT * FROM tableB b
   WHERE a.code = b.code
   ORDER BY city, county
   FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
)

      CODE     EMP_NO       CODE CITY  COUNTY  
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
       101      11111        101 City1 Country1
       102      22222        102 City4 Country2
       103      33333        103 City5 Country3
       104      44444                          
       105      55555
```

Comment: Thanks, this is simple! But it is 11g. Can we use something equivalent like this on 11g?

Answer (score 2):

using row_number() function and get records where `row_number()` `= 1`

```
SELECT select a.code,
       a.emp_no,
       b.city,
       b.county
FROM   table_a a
       left join (SELECT code,
                         city,
                         county,
                         row_number()
                           over (
                             PARTITION BY code
                             ORDER BY city, county ) rn
                  FROM   table_b) b
              ON b.code = a.code
                 WHERE rn = 1 OR rn IS NULL;
```

Note: It is still unclear from the question what actually this means.

> first record from the "right" joined table

Comment: That currently only gives you the `b.code` value for one code from `a`, and you already have that; it doesn't give you the city/county for any rows?

Comment: My first record is based on LST_UPD_TSTMP (real situation). I don't understand what I supposed to use in **id**: `PARTITION BY id`.

Comment: @IgorIvanov - looks like you would use `PARTITION BY code`. But at the moment that won't show the 104 or 105 rows; you could change the last line to `WHERE rn IS NULL OR rn = 1` to fix that...

Comment: @Alex Poole Edited as per advice.Thanks!